# jQuery - 2 identical forms, only want to validate the submitted form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have two identical forms with identical classes, I want to check if the fields are empty only for the submitted form - not for both forms.

Form HTML:

```
<form class="booking-form">

    <input type="text" name="pickup-address" class="pickup-address" />

    <button type="button" class="bookingbutton">
        <span>Reserve Now</span>
    </button>

</form>
```

JS:

```
$(".booking-form").on('click', '.bookingbutton', function () {

    if ( $(".pickup-address").val() == '') {        
        alert('Please enter a pickup location');
        return false;
    }

});
```

The code I'm using works fine, but it checks both forms, I only want it to check for the form which the submit button was clicked on.

I know I could give each form a unqiue class but this isn't an option, so can I use $(this) to some how check only the form the submit button was clicked form?

Comment: are both forms on the same page? because `id`s should be _unique_ to each page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using jQuery it is possible to traverse up and down the DOM from a clicked element. In this case you could try using [`.closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to traverse up to the nearest `.booking-form` and then use that to search for your `input`

I would also suggest adding a `required` attribute on the `input` to have to browser provide some feedback about the element too.

```
$(".booking-form").on('click', '.bookingbutton', function () {
    // find the closest form, because we have delegated the event, $(this) refers to the .bookingbutton element
    var form = $(this).closest('.booking-form');
    // check we found a form
    if(form.length === 0) return;

    // search within the found form for the .pickup-address
    if ( form.find(".pickup-address").val() == '') {        
        alert('Please enter a pickup location');
        return false;
    }
});
```

As an alternative suggestion, you could toggle either the visibility, or `disabled` state of the `.bookingbutton` based upon the contents of any/all of your required fields

Comment: Works great, a nice simple solution, thanks for your help!